# Adding loading window into ASP.NET website like child window in Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a website written in C# / ASP.NET. I try to add  loading/waiting window while that page is loading. How can I do that in Asp.net? Thanks..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with DOJO. I used dijit.dialog. Here is a part of my code:

```
<head>
<!-- api's (you can use also google apis: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js) -->
    <link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css")%>" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/dojo/dojo/resources/dojo.css")%>" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" media="screen" />
     <script djconfig="parseOnLoad: true" type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/dojo/dojo/dojo.js")%>"> </script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">

dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");


// This is the function to show the spinning whell (or something else to demonstrate the loading progress)

    function wheelShow() {
        var dialog = new dijit.Dialog({ title: "Loading...", id: "wheel" });
        dialog.setContent("<img style='height: 55px; width: 55px; text-align:center' src='../../Content/images/loader.gif' />");
        dialog.show();
        // hiding of close button in dialog
        dojo.query("#wheel .dijitDialogCloseIcon").forEach(function(node, index, arr) {
            node.style.visibility = "hidden";
        });
    }
</script>

<body class="tundra">
    <!-- after the page will be completly loaded - hide the wheel -->
    <div id="delayedContent" onload="dijit.byId('wheel').hide()">


<!-- your page content here... -->


    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something like that. It seems easy and practical to use :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42344/AJAX-Enabled-MessageBox

Thanks for your answer by the way.